# Why is the python code in the zip package after py2app is packaged?

Tags: python, py2app, cythonize

Who is familiar with py2app, how can the python code packaged by py2app not be placed in a tarball. And can be converted to so file

Answer (score 0):

py2app does not support creating a shared library with the application's python code.